# Evaluate the limit where $a,b,c>0$

Tags: limits

> If $a,b,c>0$ then evaluate $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{a^x+b^x+c^x}{x}\right)^{\frac{2}{x}}$$

Imo, the limit does not exist. Even wolframaplha wasn't able to calculate it.

I tried taking $\ln$ both sides but the $x$ in denominator keeps making things hard.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left hand limit is not defined, so I  will take the right hand limit. Dropping $b^{x}$ and $c^{x}$ we get $(\frac{a^x+b^x+c^x}{x})^{\frac{2}{x}}\geq a^{2}e^{-(2/x) \ln x} \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**. You can try using [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule):

\begin{align}
lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{a^x+b^x+c^x}{x}\right)^{\frac{2}{x}}&=lim_{x\rightarrow0}\exp\left(\log\left(\frac{a^x+b^x+c^x}{x}\right)^{\frac{2}{x}}\right)\\
&=\exp\left(lim_{x\rightarrow0}\log\left(\frac{a^x+b^x+c^x}{x}\right)^{\frac{2}{x}}\right)\\
&=\exp\left(lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{2}{x}\log\left(\frac{a^x+b^x+c^x}{x}\right)\right)\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{a^x+b^x+c^x}{x}\right)^{\frac{2}{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}e^{\ln{\left(\frac{a^x+b^x+c^x}{x}\right)^{\frac{2}{x}}}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}e^{\frac{2}{x}\ln{\left(\frac{a^x+b^x+c^x}{x}\right)}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}e^{\left(\frac{2}{x}\ln\left(a^x+b^x+c^x\right)-\frac{2}{x}\ln\left(x\right)\right)}.
$$